# Python coverting list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to write a function which takes a list of strings containing names and
marks as a parameter. And return a dictionary of (mark, [list of names who got that mark])

Example:

```
def example(["John,5", "Jessica,5", "Jack,7"]):
```

Returns:

```
{'5' : ["John", "Jessica"], '7' : "Jack"}
```

I find this a tricky problem... How would I solve this using split(',')

This is what I've done so far:

```
def create_marks_dict(my_list):
    dictionary = {}

    for name in my_list:
        if name not in dictionary:
            dictionary[name]
    return dictionary
```

Comment: You're basically going to get a rehash of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049794/python-list-to-dict), but with `key, value = item.split(",")`.

Comment: `def example(["John,5", "Jessica,5", "Jack,7"]):` is invalid syntax.

Comment: And are you sure you want `{'5' : ["John", "Jessica"], '7' : "Jack"}` and not `{'5' : ["John", "Jessica"], '7' : ["Jack"]}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use *defaultdict* from *collections* to use lists in your dictionary

```
from collections import defaultdict
def create_marks_dict(my_list):    
    dictionary = defaultdict(list)
    for item in my_list:                                              
        name, marks=item.split(',')
       dictionary[marks].append(name)                               
    return dictionary
```

output:

```
{'5' : ["John", "Jessica"], '7' : "Jack"}
```

If output of `dict` is required instead of `defaultdict`, you can cast `dictionary` while returning

```
return dict(dictionary)
```

Comment: Is there a way of not having `defaultdict(<class 'list'>,` with the output?

Comment: You could cast it to a classic one: `dict(defaultdict(...))`

Comment: If the function call is `print create_marks_dict(...)` and its output is `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {...})`, then if you want to print it like
a normal dictionary, you can convert the result of the function to a `dict` by using `print dict(create_marks_dict(...))`

Comment: @AshokaLella Are you sure about the output? I'd rather think that `Jack` is in a list on its own as well, such as `{'5': ['John', 'Jessica'], '7': ["Jack"]}`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use collections.defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

marksdict = defaultdict(list)

for entry in ["John,5", "Jessica,5", "Jack,7"]:
   name,mark = entry.split(',')
   marksdict[mark].append(name)

print marksdict
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the version that uses plain python dictionary:

```
def get_dict(nm_list):
    d = {}
    for n, m in [(name, mark) for (name, mark) in \
                tuple([nm.split(',') for nm in nm_list])]:
        d[m] = [n] if m not in d else d[m]+[n]
    return d

la = ['John,5', 'Jessica,5', 'Jack,7']
d = get_dict(la)
print d
```

The output is: {'5': ['John', 'Jessica'], '7': ['Jack']}

Comment: If I have 3 items with `,5`, I'll probably end in something like `[['John', 'Jessica'], 'Jacob']` with this code. This is probably not wanted.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, thanks for pointing out. Could you suggest an improved list comprehension?

Comment: Hard to tell. I would go with the `defaultdict` approach and accept that even a single entry (such as `Jack` here) is in a list as well. I'm sure it is easier to handle after all...

Comment: if single entry is allowed in a list not a string, I can do this using the list comprehension. I have changed the code accordingly.

Comment: This violates the central tenets of Python: it is unreadable, the variable and method names are meaningless, there is an unnecessary line continuation and a needless triadic operator. Compare this to the selected answer for how to do it correctly.